# Is It Illegal For The IRS To Target Groups Based On Political Views?

Tags: united-states, constitution, congress

This morning Steven Miller, outgoing IRS Commissioner, testified in front of Congress that it is **not** illegal for the IRS to target certain groups based on their political ideology:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvPq88mRpMU

Is he correct or is it in fact illegal? If it is, in fact, illegal, please cite relevant law.  If it is not, why is this not a form of prohibited discrimination?

Comment: My answer to the other [IRS/Tea Party Q](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/why-is-targeted-scrutiny-from-the-irs-bad/1458#1458) covers this. The equal protection clause is the law, [Yick Wo v Hopkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yick_Wo_v._Hopkins) would be an example of a SCOTUS case based on it. Worse yet, imagine if it wasn't illegal. The IRS could choose to have a tax holiday for everyone who registered Democrat. Then the next election cycle, whomever won could promise the same (since tax audits can go back 3 years, you better make sure your party wins :) )

Comment: As I understand it, a tax audit can go back 7 years.

Comment: The reality of course is that the IRS Comissioner didn't make that statement (or conduct the investigations) without taking legal advice. Of course all that proves is that he, and his lawyers, don't believe what they did was illegal. The only way it can be definitively decided if it is illegal or not is when it comes to court.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - It can go back further than that if you have an ongoing crime.  So if your company is shown to have been laundering money and evading taxes for 10 years they can audit all 10 years.  But if you stop doing it 7 years earlier and then pick it back up a year later then it is not an ongoing crime.

Answer (score 3):

Many tax classifications, such as 501(c)(3) non-profit status, have requirements including lack of participation in political lobbying or campaigning. If certain groups, identified by any category not protected from discrimination under the law, are statistically more likely to engage in these activities, then the IRS is not only allowed but *obligated* to target those groups for tighter scrutiny.

Comment: I don't really think this addresses the OP's question: can the IRS target groups of a specific political affiliation?

Comment: The issue is mainly related to 501(c)(4) groups, not 501(c)(3) charities. Moreover, the targeting wasn't so much based on the nature of a group (political vs non-political) but the beliefs of a group (conservative, religious) and subjects related to their thoughts like what books they read, what the posted on social media, and in one case, the contents of their prayers. While there are protected groups, is there also protected thoughts or speech that should be considered legally?

Comment: @Avi is "political affiliation" a category protected from discrimination? (it's not) If not, then this answer applies.

Comment: Yeah, so you should put in your answer that there is no prohibition against he IRS targeting specific political ideologies.

Comment: @TomD that is speculation at this point. As for protected speech, the issue would be if said speech is political in nature, which is potentially breaking the regulations of the tax-exempt status--and therefore not a free-speech issue but rather a tax-code issue.

Comment: @DA What part of what I said is speculation? I watched the hearing and it didn't seem very speculative to me. Also, 501(c)(4) orgs are allowed to engage in political speech. The organizations in question were mostly 501(c)(4) orgs with the exception of the few religious orgs which were 3s.

Comment: @TomD maybe I'm behind on my news, but has it been shown the groups were targeted based on their books and prayers--or were they being targeted because they appeared to be political groups? As for 'political speech' that seems to be a big part of this entire mess--the laws seem vague enough as to what these groups can and can't do that I find it hard for anyone to properly enforce them regardless of particular political leanings. Somehow an IRS worker has to draw a line between 'Social Welfare' and 'lobbying'? That seems ripe for mistakes, at best; this current mess, at worse.